# How to redirect mobile visitors from drupal site to mobile site on other domain

Tags: drupal, mobile, redirect, drupal-7

I wondering about the best way to redirect mobile users from my drupal site to a seperate mobile site on a different url.

I've looked at [mobile tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) but it seems a little to heavy for my needs.  I've done this with flat html/php files using a [mobile detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/) script and it works perfectly and is very straight forward.

I'm supposing that I can't use .htaccess for this and any solution has to come from drupal.  But I'm wondering about where to put the code so that it's executed first.

Any ideas/tips/help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be to write a small module and implement [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) which happens before the page is even built.

```
function MYMODULE_init() {
  include("PATH/TO/Mobile_Detect.php");

  $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
  if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: http://newdomain.com/');
    drupal_exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: What abut using hook_boot which is called before hook_init?  That way the modules haven't even been loaded.  Or is there a reasn to use init instead?

Comment: Yep hook_boot would be even better I can't think of a reason it wouldn't work

Comment: hook_init won't be called for cached pages.